# How to check if GetOpenFilename with MultiSelect was canceled?

Tags: vba, excel

`GetOpenFilename` with `MultiSelect := True` either returns a array of Variant or Boolean `False` if the dialog was canceled. How can I make a decent check?
If I check the return value against `False`, I get a type mismatch error when files are selected (i.e. the dialog is not canceled) because apparently I cannot check if a `Variant()` is `False`.

I now check for "Boolean" type, which works. But I feel dirty having written this code. Is there a decent way?

```
Dim files As Variant
files = Application.GetOpenFilename("Alle-Dateien (*.*),*.*,", , "please choose files", "open", MultiSelect:=True)
If TypeName(files) = "Boolean" Then 
    MsgBox "Nothing selected"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: In Excel 2016 the boolean check `If files = false` works fine. According to help that's the way it works. I wonder why it's not working for you.

Comment: In Excel 2013, the check only works, if cancel is pressed. If one or more files are selected, files will contain a Variant() which gives a type mismatch error when compared to `False`.

Comment: Oh, of course. I always use the FileDialog one, Seems to me, it doesn't have that issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219843(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: If you posted a solution using FileDialog, I could accept that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I like to use `FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)` (along with its folder counterpart, msoFileDialogFolderPicker). It behaves more cleanly than what you are experiencing with GetOpenFileName. I've sometimes wondered why both dialogs exist:

```
Private Sub PickSomeFiles()
Dim fdFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim SelectedItemsCount As Long
Dim i As Long

Set fdFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With fdFileDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Alle-Dateien (*.*),*.*", "*.*"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
    .Title = "please choose files"
    .ButtonName = "open"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SelectedItemsCount = .SelectedItems.Count
    For i = 1 To SelectedItemsCount
        MsgBox "You selected: " & .SelectedItems(i)
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

False = 0. Checking if files=0 should help...

Answer (score 0):

use the isarray on the return value, cancel = not array, 1 or files isarray is true.
if isarray(return) then read files else exit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).